# db2 - What is purpose of db2ln and its file system symbolic links?

Tags: db2, installation, db2-luw, instance, db2-11.5

On Linux/x86-64 I have Db2 v11.1 installed. When I tried to install Db2 v11.5 alongside existing Db2 installation I got error "*DBI1004W  /usr/lib/libdb2.so detected*".

I checked and I see symbolic links on paths:

```
ls -l /usr/lib | grep "/opt/ibm/db2/"
ls -l /usr/include | grep "/opt/ibm/db2"
```

In error description is suggestion to delete those links. After using `db2rmln` command those links are removed.

Installation of Db2 v11.5 was now successful. But I have checked and those symbolic links are not recreated. According to https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=servers-multiple-db2-copies-one-system-linux-unix this works as intended. Info: "*Links must not be created when multiple Db2 copies are intended to coexist.*"

It is so fine those symbolic links do not exist if multiple copies of Db2 resist on the same Linux.

My question is, what is purpose of those symbolic links and can I expect some problems not having them any more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a relate link for the older Db2 9.7 version: [Creating links for DB2 files](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/9.7?topic=installation-creating-links-db2-files).

> This task is not required for normal DB2 database operation.
> Consider creating links for the DB2 database system files only if both of the
> following conditions are met:
>
> - You have only one copy of DB2 database on the current computer.
> - **You are developing or running applications and want to avoid having to specify the full path to the product libraries and include
>   files.**